# WooCommerce REST API : query products by multiple attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

According to the API : [http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products](http://API) we can filter products by a single attribute. But Is it impossible to search by multiple attributes through API ?

Example : "I want **red** shirts". Here attribute is `color` and attribute term is `red`. To accomplish the search, the query string goes like this : `products?category=17&attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=22&`

And we get the red shirts only.

But for "I want **red** **medium** shirts" , here an additional `size` attribute with value `medium` is encountered. And according to the API there is no way to associate both the `color` and the `size` attributes in the query string. So the query -

```
products?category=17&attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=22&attribute=pa_size&attribute_term=24&
```

returns all products from the store

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to request like this:

```
products?attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=51,50&per_page=100
```

Its worked for me.
Latest woocommerce-api wc/v2!

Comment: this only works with de ID's of the terms, not the value.

Comment: I just tried this in V3 but it doesn't works :(    ----> 

this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products?attribute=pa_color&attribute_term=66,65&per_page=100")

Comment: can we add multiple attributes like products?attribute=pa_color,pa_size&attribute_term=51,50

Answer (score 3):

I have written custom query that does it all :D 
This is a callback function. All you need to do is create new endpoint with this callback:

**Here is a documentation:**

```
category - string (category slug) - filter by products category.
per_page - int (default - from admin) - show items on one page.
offset - int (default - 1) - show page number.
order - string (ASC/DESC, default: desc) - order products ascending or descending.
orderby - string (name, price, default: name) - order products by key.
filter - array
[pa_attribute_name (string) ]  = array of ID's.
[min_price (string) ] = int.
[max_price (string) ] = int.
```

**Example:**

```
/wp-json/go/v1/products/?category=smartphones&filter[pa_brand]=87,88&filter[pa_colour]=17&filter[min_price]=1&filter[max_price]=50&per_page=10&offset=1&order=DESC&orderby=price
```

**Here is a function:**

```
public function get_products_list_callback( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $params = $request->get_params();

    $category = General_Helper::get_array_value( 'category', $params );
    $filters  = General_Helper::get_array_value( 'filter', $params );
    $per_page = General_Helper::get_array_value( 'per_page', $params );
    $offset   = General_Helper::get_array_value( 'offset', $params );
    $order    = General_Helper::get_array_value( 'order', $params );
    $orderby  = General_Helper::get_array_value( 'orderby', $params );

    $output = [];

    // Use default arguments.
    $args = [
      'post_type'      => Config::POST_TYPE_SLUG_PRODUCT,
      'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
      'post_status'    => 'publish',
      'paged'          => 1,
    ];

    // Posts per page.
    if ( ! empty( $per_page ) ) {
      $args['posts_per_page'] = $per_page;
    }

    // Pagination, starts from 1.
    if ( ! empty( $offset ) ) {
      $args['paged'] = $offset;
    }

    // Order condition. ASC/DESC.
    if ( ! empty( $order ) ) {
      $args['order'] = $order;
    }

    // Orderby condition. Name/Price.
    if ( ! empty( $orderby ) ) {
      if ( $orderby === 'price' ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
      } else {
        $args['orderby'] = $orderby;
      }
    }

    // If filter buy category or attributes.
    if ( ! empty( $category ) || ! empty( $filters ) ) {
      $args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';

      // Category filter.
      if ( ! empty( $category ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = [
          'taxonomy' => Config::TAXONOMY_SLUG_PRODUCT,
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => [ $category ],
        ];
      }

      // Attributes filter.
      if ( ! empty( $filters ) ) {
        foreach ( $filters as $filter_key => $filter_value ) {
          if ( $filter_key === 'min_price' || $filter_key === 'max_price' ) {
            continue;
          }

          $args['tax_query'][] = [
            'taxonomy' => $filter_key,
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => \explode( ',', $filter_value ),
          ];
        }
      }

      // Min / Max price filter.
      if ( isset( $filters['min_price'] ) || isset( $filters['max_price'] ) ) {
        $price_request = [];

        if ( isset( $filters['min_price'] ) ) {
          $price_request['min_price'] = $filters['min_price'];
        }

        if ( isset( $filters['max_price'] ) ) {
          $price_request['max_price'] = $filters['max_price'];
        }

        $args['meta_query'][] = \wc_get_min_max_price_meta_query( $price_request );
      }
    }

    $the_query = new \WP_Query( $args );

    if ( ! $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      return $output;
    }

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();

      $output[] = get_the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $output;
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @mustra, does it support in woocom/v3 API?

Answer (score 2):

after test on WooRest API v3, you can pass multiple term taxonomy IDs.
You have to pass a string with ids separated by comma, this will be parsed as an array by WooRest API v3.

Like this :

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?category=1,2,3,4
```

Don't forget to encode query parameter or use Automattic\WooCommerce package
Enjoy,

Answer (score 1):

I just looked into the woocommerce rest api implementation at

```
plugins/woocommerce/includes/api/class-wc-rest-products-controller.php
```

file but unfortunately their codes doesn't support multiple attributes.
But you can write your own query to achieve your goal.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 'red' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_size',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 'Long' ),
        ),
    ),
),
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
print_r($products);
```

Comment: I don't have the option to go for a plugin. So, I am left with the search result filtering option.

Comment: Hi @Md.ArafatAlMahmud Do you find a solution?