# Filtering WooCommerce Products by Multiple Attributes via REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on integrating WooCommerce REST API into my headless website, and I'm currently facing an issue with implementing product filters. My requirement involves filtering products based on multiple attributes simultaneously. However, upon consulting the WooCommerce documentation, I noticed that the API only seems to allow filtering by one attribute at a time when passing multiple attributes in the query string.

Here's an example of what I've tried:

# Example API call

```
GET /wp-json/wc/v3/products?attribute=attribute1&attribute=attribute2&attribute_term=value1&attribute_term=value2
```

In this scenario, I'm attempting to filter products by both **`attribute1`** and **`attribute2`**, with corresponding terms **`value1`** and **`value2`**. However, it seems that only the last attribute provided (**`attribute2`**) is being considered for filtering, while **`attribute1`** is ignored.

I've reviewed the WooCommerce documentation and haven't found a clear solution for filtering by multiple attributes simultaneously. Could someone please advise on the correct approach or if there's an alternative method to achieve this?

Comment: You can add multiple terms but I don’t believe it’s possible to add more than [one attribute at a time](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/27370). However, multiple `attribute_terms` can also be written using the ID of attribute terms, like this: `attribute_term=51,50` . A good approach in your goal would be to write your own query and function as in this [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54226911/10497022).